# Where is _s_entry_footer(); defined in the Underscores theme?

Tags: wordpress, underscores-wp

I'm building a theme based off Underscores.me. I'd like to modify what is output in content.php:

```
<footer class="entry-footer">
    <?php _s_entry_footer(); ?>
</footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
```

But I can't find anywhere where _s_entry_footer() is defined. Rather than the output having "Posted in [category]", I'd like to simply list the category.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be in in your theme folder under inc/template-tags..

Hope this helps

Take care and happy coding.

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I missed that. Must have looked at it a dozen times.